# How to configure Panel Background Image in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, vb.net, background-image

I have a dynamic background image url in my web application. I used javascript to re-size my panel depending on the screen resolution. However, my background image "repeats" on larger resolution. How do I set my background image to "fit" the screen resolution programmatically?

This is my javascript on back-end:

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var swidth = $(window).width();
        var sheight = $(window).height();
      $("#<%=Panel1.ClientID %>").height((sheight / 1.4) + "px"); 
        $("#<%=Panel1.ClientID %>").width((swidth / 1.8) + "px");
    });
     </script>
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: try background-size: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; in css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
panel.Attributes.Add("style", "background-repeat:no-repeat");
panel1.BackImageUrl = "~/Images/yourimage.png";
background-size:cover;
```

Comment: Hi! I did that but the image only fit 2/3 of the screen. I'm trying to fit the image to the whole panel.

Comment: background-size:cover;